# How do you load an image to form from file via keydown?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a super basic program that involves a picture and sound popping up every time I click F4. I have the background of the program set to green, because I am going to be using it as a green screen for the picture. I don't have much experience with VB, but since I couldn't find a program to do this on the web, I decided to take a swing and try to make it myself. (Failed...) Anyways, this is what I got so far.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If (Chr(KeyAscii) = "115") Then Form1.Picture = loadpicture("directory")
End Sub
End Class
```

Note: "Directory" is not what I have in loadpicture().

Comment: So are you looking for help loading pictures ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.KeyPreview = True 'This enable the key event on the form (me).
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F4 Then Me.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:\image.jpg")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code that also includes an audio clip that plays when the key is pressed as well!

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.KeyPreview = True 'This enable the key event on the form (me).
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F4 Then Me.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:\image.jpg")
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F4 Then My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\audio.wav", AudioPlayMode.Background)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F4 Then Me.BackgroundImage = Nothing
End Sub
End Class
```